# AFrame / Three.js : why so many (JS)Strings in memory, when loading complex .obj files?

Tags: javascript, web, memory, three.js, aframe

we have a pretty complex webscene where we dynamically load pretty complex .obj- and .mtl-files. 
After comparing the scene without any of these objects with the one that has multiple objects inside we noticed a weird behaviour:

firefox memory heap shows that most of the memory (>100MB for 5 Objects) is used for *JSStrings*. the rest of the memory is used for *Objects* which is self-explaining when we have complex object files in there.
But how come the high amount of Strings and are we able to reduce it?  Does AFrame convert the content of the .obj-files into strings?

We thought about minimizing the .obj files itself and reducing vertices. Maybe someone of you made similar experiences and / or can give us suggestions how to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: It has to fetch and load the raw OBJ file (as text), which is a string. And then it parses, to objects. How large are the OBJ/MLT files?

Comment: our file sizes are between 1 and 50 MB

Comment: Yeah, it's Don's answer then. The memory you are seeing is the text of the model files fetched in and cached (which is then parsed). You could try to free the memory from the three.js network Cache. (`delete THREE.Cache.files['someurl']`)

Comment: Ye, I think converting is the only real option. But your delete method looks interesting too, I will give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OBJ files are text-based, and unfortunately not a particularly efficient way to transfer 3D data. A-Frame has to parse that text to get your data uploaded to the GPU.

If you need to avoid that, I'd suggest trying to convert your OBJ files to a binary format like glTF (`.glb`). You can do that conversion with [obj2gltf](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/obj2gltf) (CLI) or https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html (web). A glTF file will load more quickly.

Comment: thanks for your good explanation and your suggestion too. The Problem with gltf-files is that our designer works with "Rhino" and is only able to export the models in OBJ format. 
But the conversion thing is a very good point. Maybe we should test if converting the OBJ files to glTF and loading them is faster than just loading the OBJs. 
Do you know what else we could do to reduce the string usage? Reduce the number of rows in the OBJ, reducing number of vertices or even manipulate some AFrame functions?

Comment: IMHO, OBJ is a terrible format. Its material handling is super limited.. it requires multiple files to package assets.. its text based.. it doesn't support compression. It cant really handle hierarchical/nested objects, and there are a zillion variations of the format as different companies have tried to address its shortcomings.

Comment: GLTF otoh is a very modern format, specifically designed with internet content delivery in mind. It supports full scene descriptions, and modern material formats like PBR. It supports mesh compression, and the binary flavor allows you to pack all relevant model components in a single file. It supports metadata as well so you can store your own application data within the file, thus allowing single file asset interchange. The sooner we increase adoption of it, the sooner all modelling software will be able to have seamless interop.

Comment: It also has 2 flavors, text and binary... so if you really need textual data in order to debug your pipeline, its all there, and human readable.

Comment: "Maybe we should test if converting the OBJ files to glTF" — well, converting them  in JavaScript won't be faster. But you can convert them in advance, offline, and then just use the glTF files in your application. Perhaps Rhino will get glTF support in the future: https://mcneel.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/RH-42754

Comment: Today I diskussed your suggestions with my colleague and I think we will focus on converting the OBJs to glTF. We think it is the only solution so I will mark your answer as accepted. really appreciated your help